# What exactly is an .EBIN file and how can I access its contents?

Tags: erlang, erlang-shell

A friend of mine has a problem. He has hundreds of highly confidential .EBIN files for a medical study created by a person that is no longer available.

I figured that it's probably an Erlang directory - I downloaded Erlang and looked for several file type specifications, but I just can't find a way to "open" this binary file.

I feel really stupid right now as I should be able to easily access this as a long-term programmer, but I'm clueless. I don't even know what to enter into a search engine.

Comment: Have you tried opening them in a text editor, to see if there is any intelligible contents? Or does your friend have access to a code repo that might contain code designed to read these files? Could they be encrypted?

Comment: i actually think it's encrypted, yes. i have opened it with a text editor and a hex editor, it's just some random binary garbage. it seems like something a program would put out, maybe even with encryption. i am not so sure what to think about it - since .ebin is a file extension, and ebin/ (the erlang folder) is an actual folder...

Comment: If it is encrypted then you may also need to find out (a) what encryption algorithm was used, and (b) what key/passwords was used. If you don't have the latter - say in your colleague's old files - you could be well and truly stuck.

Comment: It is also possible that this has nothing to do with Erlang at all. `ebin` is conventionally the name of a **directory** in Erlang applications and **not** a file extension.

Comment: Yes. That is what I figured now as well.

Answer (score 2):

I'd guess that they are just containing serialized Erlang data ("terms"). Try starting Erlang and entering the following from the Erlang shell:

```
erlang:binary_to_term(element(2,file:read_file("YOURFILE.EBIN"))).
```

See http://erlang.org/doc/man/erlang.html#term_to_binary-2 for details about the term_to_binary() function and see http://erlang.org/doc/apps/erts/erl_ext_dist.html for details about the term format. If the bytes on disk don't look like this, it's likely that the binary data has also been encrypted before writing it on disk.

Comment: Thank you for the direction! Somehow, Erlang does not output anything inside the shell. Is there any print-like function?

Comment: It should print the result of the expression. Did you write the terminating '.' before hitting Enter? Erlang's shell keeps reading input until it gets a period followed by newline.